# Error INVALID_USER_OFFSET from template for XOffset

Tags: docusignapi

We just went live with our approved Docusign key and we are in the process of on boarding our first client. The client has about 52 templates set up in their account already. Around 8 of those templates throw an error when attempting to create an envelope with them like this:

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_USER_OFFSET",
  "message": "The specified User Offset exceeds the page boundaries. XOffset " -432 " is invalid. Tab Label: Signature 73272."
}
```

The client has moved that Signature tab around the document several times and the value changes correspondingly but the error remains.

Any areas of the API I should check or general steps to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the anchor string being used in those templates is unique? If you are matching against an unexpected string somewhere in the document that may be the culprit.

Comment: @Luis Scott- Your answer is correct, thank for your help.